# How to Make Windows 2012 Share Display in Windows 7 Network

Tags: windows-7, network-share, windows-server-2012

I'm setting up a Windows 2012 Essentials machine to be a local file server.  I've got the shares setup and I can access the shares from my OSX computer.  My Win7 machine can only acces it by typing `\\<server_name>` in the address bar of windows explorer.

Is there a way to get the server to automatically show up in the 'Network' section of the Win7 computer?

EDIT:

This is just a small home network.  All computers are on the same subnet.

Server IP: 192.168.1.175

Win7 IP: 192.168.1.130

Netmask: 255.255.255.0

Gateway:192.168.1.1

DNS: 192.168.1.1

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But without adding some detail to your question, you're unlikely to get a more detailed answer. [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask) might be of use to you.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details.  This is my first foray into Windows Server so I'm not sure what information is relevant.  What details would be helpful?

Comment: Try adding some details about the network configuration (IP/Mask/DNS/Gateway). Are both systems on the same subnet? are you using AD? Please edit your question and add this info in, once there is enough detail, your question stands a good chance of being reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, if you set the Workgroup name to be the same on all the machines, they should appear in the Network browser.